# Code snippets don't work every time after new VS 2022 update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

After I updated my VS 2022 before a couple of days, the built in snippet cw(tab+tab) for Console.WriteLine(); stopped working as before. Sometimes it works , but sometimes not. Its like 50/50 . I have one more snippet that I use, this time custom - cr(tab+tab) --> var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); , but it doesnt work every time also.

Here you can see screen from VS
[image: Here you can see screen from VS]

Second photo with even more strange behaviour of cw snippet
[image: Second photo with even more strange behaviour of cw snippet]

On both screens i use cw/cr snippet on every line and as you see i get different results.
Are you having the same problem or is it local. And do you have any ideas ? Thanks.

I saw somewhere that Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense > 'Always include snippets' maybe could fix it , but nothing changed. Tried using .Net Core 3.1 , .NET 6 / 7 and its the same.

Comment: I don't have this problem with VS2022 community version 17.4.2. What version are you using? Have you tried the repair in the installer? "Stop working like before", how did you ever fix it?

Comment: I am using version 17.4.4 . What you mean by repair the installer ?

Comment: Please check the photo. Open vs installer and select repair in more.https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4iEV.png

Comment: Did it. Same thing. It works with cw(esc+tab) , but not with tab+tab(every time). And its not just cw, its even "for" loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem in 17.4.4
cw will work sometimes, and other times it gives strange behavior

Does cw (esc+tab) work for you?
If it does, it is a problem with the language service
If it also does not work correctly, it is a problem with the editor and you should check in Tools->Code Snippets Manager -> CSharp -> Visual C# and see if cw is there and correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. cw(esc + tab) works every time. Only when i try cw(tab+tab) or cr(tab+tab) it doesnt work every time. So as you say , its language service ... Do you know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok , so i fixed it. There is an option to Roll back version of VS. I rolled back from 17.4.4 to 17.4.1 and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with the same issue after the update. The cw snippet is just random. Sometimes it works correctly and other times it will type out things like "cw.WriteLine" or "cw=ReadLine".

I didn't think of rolling back the update and ended up doing an uninstall and reinstall which did not fix the problem.

I went into Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense and selected 'Always include snippets' but it didn't help.

I recommend reporting the problem through Visual Studio if you haven't. I've reported the problem through Visual Studio to the dev community. The report has been "triaged" but there has been no contact from the dev team yet. If I hear from them I will report back here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So , I saw a few days ago that there is a new version - 17.4.5. Did you tried it , and if so , is the problem fixed ? I am still on the roll-backed version(17.4.1)  and dont have any problem , but won't update till someone says it's safe.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @VladimirPetrov The other day I updated to the newest update but I still have the problem. It is frustrating.

Comment: @SchmeoGeo Hey, i saw there is a newer update - 17.5.1 , did you tried it ? Is the problem fixed ? I am still on 17.4.1.

Comment: @VladimirPetrov I just updated to 17.5.1 and tested it out. I typed cw tab tab thirty times and out of those thirty times four were incorrect outputs. The incorrect outputs were "cw.Close();", "cw = null;", "cw2 = null;", and "cw3 = null;"

Comment: @SchmeoGeo Thanks for the answer. So the problem is still there. I wont update for now. You can check 17.4.1. version. (the last version without that bug , atleast for me.)

Comment: @VladimirPetrov Yeah. This problem is pretty frustrating. If I had the option to rollback the update I would. Or if I could somehow get a download for 17.4.1 specifically I would do that but I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: @SchmeoGeo you have an option to roll back from the VS Installer , but its probably just 1 roll back - lets say from 17.5.1 to 17.5.0 (not sure about this). You could check - is it possible to do multiple roll-backs , one after another untill you get to version 17.4.1 Cant think of other solution right now ...

Comment: @VladimirPetrov The reason I can't do a rollback is because when I first experienced the snippets issue I didn't think of rolling back the update and I ended up doing an uninstall and reinstall. After reinstalling I didn't have an option to rollback.

Comment: @SchmeoGeo yea, I undestand ... I see now that there is a newer version again. Did you check it ? Also i am thinking of reporting to VS this issue of ours.

Comment: @VladimirPetrov I just updated to 17.5.2 and I typed cw tab tab fifteen times and out of those fifteen times nine were incorrect outputs. Some of the incorrect outputs were "cw.WriteLine();", "cw = Console.ReadLine();", "cw2 = ConsoleReadLine();", "cw2.WriteLine();", "cw3 = Console.ReadLine();", "cw3.WriteLine();"

Comment: @SchmeoGeo Same as before... I am attending online C# classes and the teacher has this problem also, some of the students also. So its some kind of a general problem. I think we cant do anything , other than waiting for an update or some kind of fix ....

Comment: @VladimirPetrov Interesting, sounds more common than I thought then. Unfortunately it seems as if not many people are reporting the issue through Visual Studio. I haven't seen many reports about it in the feedback list.

Comment: @SchmeoGeo Did you have any luck with the new version 17.6.0 ?

Comment: @VladimirPetrov No unfortunately 17.6 still has the issue. I've been thinking of trying a whole reinstall of Windows to see if that will fix anything.

Comment: @SchmeoGeo i dont think reinstalling Windows will help , cuz i had this problem also , only after i updated to newer VS version. Also i've seen other people have the problem with newer versions. But ofcourse you can try. Also i suggest you provide detailed report to chat GPT and ask him how to fix it. He will give you like 5-6 points to check and verify some settings. Probably worth trying.

Comment: @VladimirPetrov Yeah reinstalling Windows might not help. I'm just trying to figure out why the majority of people have no issue after the update but some people do. I'll check with chat GPT soon. I think one reason the visual studio team isn't making this issue a priority is because other people aren't reporting it and other people aren't upvoting the issue on the report list. If you could upvote my report on the report list and get other people to upvote also that could maybe help. The link to my report is https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Intellisense-Snippets-Not-Working-Correc

Comment: @SchmeoGeo hey, long time no see. Do the new versions work?

Comment: @VladimirPetrov Hey. On 17.7.4 I typed "cw tab tab" about 45 times and only about three of those were incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I found that unchecking the `Show new snippet experience (experimental)` in `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense` fixed my snippet issues.

This worked for incomplete snippets, like they were only half typed.